# Null Pointer Exception, when trying to replace characters from file

Tags: java, file-io, jtable, bufferedreader, stringtokenizer

I am trying to replace character ( and ) from a file with a comma so that I can use the code below for entering data in to a `JTable` from a csv file. I have tried to do this by reading the file with a `StringTokenizer` and i've tried manipulating the way that I implement it and I can't get it to run with `NullPointerException`. I understand that it can't find an object that it is pointing to but i can't see where my problem is. Any pointers would be great as I've been stuck on this for hours. Is the idea of reading using a `StringTokenizer` the best one or is there a better way? The error produced is as follows.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at initial.DisplayTableModel.fileImport(DisplayTableModel.java:29)
    at initial.DisplayTableModel.(DisplayTableModel.java:15)
    at initial.Display.(Display.java:15)
    at initial.Display.main(Display.java:27)
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at initial.DisplayTableModel.getRowCount(DisplayTableModel.java:85)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getRowCount(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.createTableSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

There are two other classes included to this model but they do not return an error when the replace bracket section is commented out.

```
package initial;

import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DisplayTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    protected Vector<String> data;
    protected Vector<String> columnNames;
    protected String datafile;

    public DisplayTableModel(String f) {
        datafile = f;
        fileImport();
    }

    public void fileImport() {
        String aLine;
        data = new Vector<String>();
        columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        try {

            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(datafile);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));

            aLine = br.readLine();
            String strReplace = ")";

                br.readLine().replaceAll(strReplace, ",");
                StringTokenizer Yearquote = new StringTokenizer(aLine, ")");

                columnNames.addElement(Yearquote.nextToken());
                StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), ",");
                while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {

                    columnNames.addElement(Yearquote.nextToken());
                }

                // extract data

            while (aLine != null) {

                if (aLine.startsWith("\"")) {
                    StringTokenizer addquote = new StringTokenizer(aLine, "\"");
                    data.addElement(addquote.nextToken());
                    StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(addquote
                            .nextToken(), ",");

                    while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {

                        data.addElement(st2.nextToken());
                    }
                } else {
                    StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(aLine, ",");

                    while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {

                        data.addElement(st2.nextToken());
                    }
                }

            }

            br.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size() / getColumnCount();
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.size();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        String colName = "";

        if (columnIndex <= getColumnCount()) {
            colName = columnNames.elementAt(columnIndex);
        }
        return colName;

    }

    public Class<String> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return String.class;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return data.elementAt((rowIndex * getColumnCount()) + columnIndex);
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line number (line 29 in the stack trace) is a big tip. Most likely, `br.readline().replaceAll()` is causing the null pointer as you are calling `br.readline()` twice in a row without checking that there is content in the stream, and the second call is likely after you have exhausted the stream.

Answer (score 1):

You should also be careful with the line `return data.size() / getColumnCount();`. You might end up dividing by 0, which seems to be your case judging from the following exception lines:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at initial.DisplayTableModel.getRowCount(DisplayTableModel.java:85)
at javax.swing.JTable.getRowCount(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code around

```
while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            aLine.replaceAll(strReplace, ",");
            //logic here
        }
```

Comment: Mmmm... This can't work, it doesn't even compile :-\ You should rework your example ;o)